# Checking if site connection is secure selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm making an effort to download every image from various websites. Unfortunately, there are some issues with my code. The website which I want to scrape has direct my browser to another page with the headline "Checking if site connection is secure selenium" when I use Selenium to access it. And despite several reloads, Selenium is still inaccessible. I don't know how to change it because I'm a rookie. Because of my poor English, I can't locate the solution on Google. I've tried to install a Firefox profile, even though I'm unsure of its purpose,  but the answer is still no. Please assist me!
My code:

```py
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service("D:\Program\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe"), options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Some of the websites used to block automated access, it can be accessed manually, but you can't access through automated code.

Answer (score 2):

what works for me in selenium 4.11 is,

```
options = selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
chrome_browser.get('https://demo.seleniumeasy.com/basic-first-form- 
demo.html')
```